# Read The Docs not working with automodule

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, read-the-docs

I've written some documentation for my project (in the Python docstrings), and tested everything with Sphinx on my local computer – everything works fine, all the import work correctly and so on.
So I set up a custom environment on Read The Docs (`Python 3`, `numpydoc` and my library), added the `docs` directory (and the `docs/source` subdirectory) to my Github repo, and the build on Read The Docs passes, however, nothing is created (the `View Docs` link just shows a Nginx 404 page).
The logs are as follows:

```
State: Finished

Outcome: Passed

Version: latest

Type: html
Sphinx Standard Output



html
-----

Making output directory...
Running Sphinx v1.2.2
loading translations [en]... done
building [readthedocs]: targets for 5 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 5 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 20%] contents
reading sources... [ 40%] source/contents
reading sources... [ 60%] source/index
reading sources... [ 80%] source/kineticlib
reading sources... [100%] source/modules

looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [ 20%] contents
writing output... [ 40%] source/contents
writing output... [ 60%] source/index
writing output... [ 80%] source/kineticlib
writing output... [100%] source/modules

writing additional files... genindex search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 15 warnings.
Copying readthedocs-ext.js_t... done

Sphinx Standard Error



html
-----

/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/kineticlib.rst:11: ERROR: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: kineticlib.affinities
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/kineticlib.rst:19: ERROR: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: kineticlib.crosssection
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/kineticlib.rst:27: ERROR: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: kineticlib.errors
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/kineticlib.rst:35: ERROR: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: kineticlib.loaddata
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/kineticlib.rst:43: ERROR: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: kineticlib.omegaint
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/kineticlib.rst:51: ERROR: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: kineticlib.particles
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/kineticlib.rst:59: ERROR: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: kineticlib.probabilities
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/kineticlib.rst:67: ERROR: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: kineticlib.ratesdiss
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/kineticlib.rst:75: ERROR: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: kineticlib.ratesvibr
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/kineticlib.rst:83: ERROR: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: kineticlib.reltimes
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/kineticlib.rst:91: ERROR: Unknown directive type "automodule".

.. automodule:: kineticlib.wtpoly
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/contents.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/index.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/source/modules.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
WARNING: html_static_path entry '/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/checkouts/latest/docs/_static' does not exist

Setup Output



checkout
-----



venv
-----

Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/bin/python3
Not overwriting existing python script /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/bin/python (you must use /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/bin/python3)
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3


sphinx
-----

Requirement already up-to-date: sphinx==1.2.2 in /var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: virtualenv==1.9.1 in /var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: docutils==0.11 in /var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Downloading/unpacking readthedocs-ext from git+git://github.com/ericholscher/readthedocs-sphinx-ext
  Cloning git://github.com/ericholscher/readthedocs-sphinx-ext to /var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/build/readthedocs-ext
  Running setup.py (path:/var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/build/readthedocs-ext/setup.py) egg_info for package readthedocs-ext

    warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'readthedocs_ext'
Installing collected packages: readthedocs-ext
  Running setup.py install for readthedocs-ext

    warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'readthedocs_ext'
Successfully installed readthedocs-ext
Cleaning up...


requirements
-----

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpydoc in /var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r docs/requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): kineticlib in /var/build/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r docs/requirements.txt (line 2))
Cleaning up...


install
-----

running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/wtpoly.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/ratesvibr.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/errors.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/probabilities.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/omegaint.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/__init__.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/loaddata.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/particles.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/ratesdiss.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/reltimes.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/affinities.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
copying src/kineticlib/crosssection.py -> build/lib/kineticlib
creating build/lib/kineticlib/data
creating build/lib/kineticlib/data/models
copying src/kineticlib/data/models/dissociation.csv -> build/lib/kineticlib/data/models
copying src/kineticlib/data/models/interactions.csv -> build/lib/kineticlib/data/models
creating build/lib/kineticlib/data/particles
copying src/kineticlib/data/particles/O2.dat -> build/lib/kineticlib/data/particles
copying src/kineticlib/data/particles/n2.dat -> build/lib/kineticlib/data/particles
copying src/kineticlib/data/particles/n.dat -> build/lib/kineticlib/data/particles
creating build/lib/kineticlib/data/spectra
copying src/kineticlib/data/spectra/n2.dat -> build/lib/kineticlib/data/spectra
running install_lib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/wtpoly.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/ratesvibr.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/errors.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/probabilities.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/omegaint.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/__init__.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/loaddata.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/particles.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/ratesdiss.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/data/spectra/n2.dat -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/data/spectra
copying build/lib/kineticlib/data/particles/O2.dat -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/data/particles
copying build/lib/kineticlib/data/particles/n2.dat -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/data/particles
copying build/lib/kineticlib/data/particles/n.dat -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/data/particles
copying build/lib/kineticlib/data/models/dissociation.csv -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/data/models
copying build/lib/kineticlib/data/models/interactions.csv -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/data/models
copying build/lib/kineticlib/reltimes.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/affinities.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
copying build/lib/kineticlib/crosssection.py -> /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/wtpoly.py to wtpoly.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/ratesvibr.py to ratesvibr.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/errors.py to errors.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/probabilities.py to probabilities.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/omegaint.py to omegaint.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/loaddata.py to loaddata.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/particles.py to particles.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/ratesdiss.py to ratesdiss.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/reltimes.py to reltimes.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/affinities.py to affinities.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib/crosssection.py to crosssection.cpython-34.pyc
running install_egg_info
Removing /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib-0.6.egg-info
Writing /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/kineticlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kineticlib-0.6.egg-info

Environment Standard Error



checkout
-----



venv
-----



sphinx
-----



requirements
-----



install
-----

/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'include_package_data'
  warnings.warn(msg)
```

My `conf.py` has

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'numpydoc',
]
numpydoc_show_class_members = False
```

So, I have no idea why `automodule` is listed as an unknown directive.

Answer (score 6):

This is the first FAQ...

> My project isn’t building with autodoc First, you should check out the
>   Builds tab of your project. That records all of the build attempts
>   that RTD has made to build your project. If you see ImportError
>   messages for custom Python modules, you should **enable the virtualenv**
>   **feature in the Admin page of your project**, which will install your
>   project into a virtualenv, and allow you to specify a requirements.txt
>   file for your project.

emphasis mine..

Comment: I have that enabled already. Turns out, I had the wrong path to `conf.py` specified.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers address the issue, but I thought I'd put together a summary for troubleshooting readthedocs+autodoc for other users with issues with `autodoc` commands (`automodule`, `autoclass`, `autofunction`) in RTD but not locally with `make html` —there are multiple Qs in SE with different issues. These can be resolved by:

- **Inspect errors:** In RTD Build page one can see the Errors that arose in `view raw`.

  - A common issue is missing modules or the target module.
- **Browser hard refresh**: In a browser it is critical to do a hard refresh of the pages (Shift+refresh button). Silly but I'd say 90% of issues come from this.
- **enable autodoc** `sphinx.ext.autodoc` needs to be in `extension`.

### Notes

`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../"))` is really ugly. The same can be achieved in `.readthedocs.yml` with `path: .`. The yaml may look like this:

```
version: 2

build:
  os: ubuntu-20.04
  tools:
    python: "3.8"

sphinx:
   configuration: docs/source/conf.py
   builder: html
   fail_on_warning: false

python:
   install:
     - method: pip
       path: .
     - requirements: requirements.txt
     - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
```

Notes about the yaml:

- file:

  - If the name of the yaml file is wrong you'll get a suggestion in RTD to use one
  - If the file is incorrect the build will fail.
  - If the file is correct, nothing.
- Do specify python version
- build only html for now
- switch `fail_on_warning` for quicker troubleshooting —until the Sphinx5.0 deprecation warnings kick in

In the `config.py`, RTD will add `readthedocs_ext.readthedocs` it won't make a difference with `make html` locally —but it might in the future. `sphinx_toolbox.more_autodoc` might work best before `sphinx.ext.autodoc`:

```
extensions = [
    'readthedocs_ext.readthedocs',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx_toolbox.more_autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc']
```

If you get a missing `_static` for `html_static_path` error change:

```
html_static_path = []
```

Changing the theme will help in the formatting fixes when running `make html`.

```
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
```

The extension `sphinx_toolbox.more_autodoc.typehints` does not make Sphinx behave as a type checker, so if there are modules imported for typehinting only (`typing.TYPE_CHECKING == True`), the code needs to also check if 'sphinx':

```
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING or 'sphinx' in sys.modules:
    from foo import Foo

def to_foo(self) -> Foo:
    ...
```

Comment: just one important thing to mention here @matteo-ferla is you have to rename '.readthedocs.yaml' into '.readthedocs.yml' otherwise it will not be picked.

Comment: Ah, yes —Thanks (fixed typo). Classic blunder. Second only to `config` and `conf` mixup.