# Python docstrings to GitHub README.md

Tags: python, markdown, restructuredtext, docstring, manpage

How do I transcode Python documentation strings to a GitHub `readme.md` file?

Even though it seems like something everyone does, I cannot seem to get a decent solution and I am assuming it should be easy, so it seems unlikely folks are going throw two converters…

#### What I have tried

**pydoc**  Actually simple. The output of pydoc is manpages (groff format for Unix systems). Which is a dead end as man to md is not a thing. Via HTML, `pydoc3 -w` + pandoc, utterly munges the docstrings to bits.

**Custom code** There seems to be lots of short custom code, but for the few I tried the output does not seem to be as good as that pydoc, which has a summary, adds inherited methods and lists some attributes.

**mkdocs**. It was suggested somewhere. It just pollutes my folder as it is a misleading name as is a not docstrings > md converter, but a md > html.

**Sphinx + Pandoc.** After fixing an UTF-8 issue, I gave up on Sphinx as I have a single .py script to convert and the autodoc setting of the quickstart did not parse my script. I tried in Python to import `sphinx.ext.autodoc`, but TBH the documentation was too long and I gave up.

#### NB

There is a [year-old unanswered Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660467/automatically-generate-github-wiki-documentation-from-python-docstrings#comment60075289_29660467) on the topic, but I hope that by giving a lot more detail I will get an answer.

Comment: I believe that HTML is read fine in an `.md`, so you could write what `pydoc.HTMLDoc().docmodule(mymodule)` returns to `README.md`.

Comment: You seem to be confused as to why such tools don't exist (at least in an easy to use way). That's because generating docs from source code is generally considered not good documentation. See [How I Judge the Quality of Documentation in 30 Seconds](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2014/feb/27/how-i-judge-documentation-quality/), particularly the [Prose](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2014/feb/27/how-i-judge-documentation-quality/#prose) section. Note that Sphinx and MkDocs are both recommended tools in that article because those tools assume that you are not autogenerating it from source code.

Comment: I agree that documentation should be done well, but autogenerated from docstrings is better than none. In my specific case, I have [code in progress](https://github.com/matteoferla/mutagenesis), where to show to a non-coder I had worked on it, I munged pydoc output into md. I also have a [recreational project](https://github.com/matteoferla/DnD-battler) that I do not have the time to document —but has docstrings.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The other answers are great. But I thought I (the OP) ought to share what I do these days (a year or two after the question).

I use Sphinx and its Markdown extension. Do the following:

**TL;DR**: See [Gist snippet](https://gist.github.com/matteoferla/ba72ab12a9e5f690277e2e88551773aa).

### Sphinx-markdown-builder

You need sphinx-markdown-builder python module.

```
 pip install sphinx sphinx-markdown-builder;
```

### Run Sphinx

**Not** the `autodoc`, the `apidoc`!

```
sphinx-apidoc -o Sphinx-docs . sphinx-apidoc --full -A 'Matteo Ferla'; cd Sphinx-docs;
```

### Configuration

Fix the `conf.py` file, by following the following or just lazily copy paste the echo command below.

#### Manual

First uncomment the lines. These are otherwise commented out.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
```

Note the change to `../`

One weirdness is that the magic methods get ignored. To override this, add this anywhere:

```
def skip(app, what, name, obj, would_skip, options):
    if name in ( '__init__',):
        return False
    return would_skip
def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-skip-member', skip)
```

A thing to note: The docstrings ought to be written in restructuredtext (RST). If they are in Markdown, you need to add a mod - see [this](https://github.com/jxltom/sphinx-markdown-extension). The two are similar, but different. For example, a single backquote is required for <code> in Markdown, while two are for RST. If in doubt, several blog posts discuss the merits of RST documentation over Markdown.

### Typehinting

RST typehints (`:type variable: List`) are obsolete as proper typehinting `def foo(variable: Optional[List[int]]=None) -> Dict[str,int]:` has been introduced since 3.6. To make these work:

```
 pip install sphinx-autodoc-typehints
```

And add `'sphinx_autodoc_typehints'` at the end of the `extensions` list. Note the package has hyphens while the module has underscores.

#### TL;DR

Copy paste this:

```
echo " import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath('../'))
def skip(app, what, name, obj,would_skip, options):
    if name in ( '__init__',):
        return False
    return would_skip
def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-skip-member', skip)
extensions.append('sphinx_autodoc_typehints')
 " >> conf.py;
```

### Showtime

Then it is showtime.

```
make markdown;
```

Copy the files and clean however you fancy.

```
mv _build/markdown/* ../; rm -r Sphinx-docs;
```

### Repeat Apidoc for new files

It should be noted that when new files are added, the `apidoc` command needs to be repeated. Nevertheless, I highly recommend generating documentation midway as I often realise I am doing something wrong when I see the docs.

But briefly, apidoc will add for each file a `automodule` command, so this could be added manually or even expanded:

```
.. automodule:: my_module
   :members:
   :inherited-members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

There's also the commands `autoclass`, `autofunction`, `autoexception`, for specific cases. In the case of `autoclass` if the class inherits many base classes in separate files to rightfully keep filesizes under 250 lines, the property `:inherited-members:` is a nice addition to this —thus avoiding having to describe the private base classes.

## Read the docs: the common way

It should be said that there's a trend to **not** have documentation in GitHub but in [Read the docs](https://readthedocs.org/). My guess is because:

- avoids this docstrings-to-markdown business
- some users get confused by GitHub
- looks nicer
- other do it

Despite this, it requires some set up due to the module requirements. In [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012658/read-the-docs-not-working-with-automodule/71586732#71586732) is a long list of pitfalls and tricks —briefly IMO users, such as myself, make three mistakes:

1. missing modules or the target module
2. forget to hard refresh the browser
3. enabling the `sphinx.ext.autodoc` extension

However, if one has written markdown documentation in GitHub these can be imported too. Formerly, the `m2r2` (a fix of the deprecated `m2r`) was a good solution, but the divergence of its dependency `mistune`, which would require it to be frozen at version 0.8.4 as opposed to being at 2.0.0, which breaks other sphinx modules, therefore a new split works best and better: `sphinx-mdinclude`.
This is pip installed as `sphinx-mdinclude` but included as `sphinx_mdinclude` and allows md files to be read alongside rst files.
So a simple workaround in the `docs/source/config.py` file is to copy the files from the project root to the folder of `config.py` One issue is that links may need to be checked, especially if files moved around or are relative to the base URL (slash prefixed), eg. `[Foo](/md_docs/foo)`.

Comment: This should be pinned and placed in a blog; I've spent an entire day trying to figure out how to do that, not even the Sphinx documentation explains how to achieve this! Well done :-D

Comment: @Ælex, I so often pop over to copy off my own answer and every time it reminds me of a meme on [Reddit r/ProgrammerHumor  where Obama gives himself a medal](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/djg580/its_still_probably_wrong_though/). About the blog, I did that too ([here](http://blog.matteoferla.com/2019/11/convert-python-docstrings-to-github.html), but it's a copy to the letter).

Comment: GitHub supports also `README.rst`. Is not there a simpler solution for generating `README.rst`?

Comment: Yes, Sphinx can generate restructured text (and HTML), but it's an unflexible solution as it would require the whole file to be written in restructured text if it's actually part of a longer description. The major issue however is that Sphinx's `sphinx-apidoc` is not 100% intuitive, so the bulk of the answer still stands...

Comment: Great solution so far. I tried to find a solution as  well. First hit was `pydoc-markdown` which was kind of buggy. Worked out of the box for one file but not for another. Found a few very old implementations only using `pydoc`, but they were also deprecated. Your solution worked out of the box. You just missed the `sphinx_autodoc_typehints` dependency also in the blog completely

Comment: i wrote this:  https://github.com/AtakamaLLC/docmd

it's easier than all the others.  not as feature rich.  but i dont care.   works fine.

Answer (score 7):

I've found [pydoc-markdown](https://niklasrosenstein.github.io/pydoc-markdown/) quite easy to use. The first command will install the library and the second one will create a README from your module named `MY_MODULE`:

```
pip install pydoc-markdown
pydoc-markdown -m MY_MODULE -I $(pwd) > README.md
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I found it very useful. To generate markdown for one file containing a couple of classes, I just ran `pydoc-markdown  -p . --render-toc >ne1.md` from the folder with the `ne1.py` file. It made a perfectly usable `ne1.md`. Thanks! (I used sphinx docstrings because they are compact and simple.)

Answer (score 5):

I have found some other options for doing this:

### https://github.com/coldfix/doc2md

> Little convenience tool to extract docstrings from a module or class and convert them to GitHub Flavoured Markdown. Its purpose is to quickly generate README.md files for small projects.

### https://github.com/freeman-lab/myopts

> This module provides a command line tool for parsing a Python file and generating nice looking markdown with your function definitions. It's extremely opinionated and rigid! But also extremely easy to use.

Comment: i wrote this:  https://github.com/AtakamaLLC/docmd.

Answer (score 2):

I have a little bit of code that I use to generate an index file from a project. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but with a little wiggle you could add an if statement for py files (where I only have html and png) and grab the **doc** = "your DocStrings."...
https://gist.github.com/Krewn/6e9acdadddb4bf2a56c0

```
# WARNING RUNNING THIS FILE WILL OVERIDE EXISTING readme.md FILE IN CWD

import os

class indexer:
    path = "~"
    username = "" # !!! Enter your github username in the provided quotes.
    site = "http://"+username+".github.io"
    proj = ""     # !!! Enter your repository name in provided quotes.
    prod = []
    loc=[]

    def __init__(self,p):
        self.path=p
    def fprep(self,name):
        name.replace(".","")
        name.replace("\\","/")
        return(name)
    def refPrep(self):
        ref = self.site+"/"+self.proj
        for qw in self.loc:
            ref+="/"+qw
        return(ref)
    def HtmlFrek(self,adir):
        self.loc.append(adir)
        os.chdir(adir)
        pys = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.split(".")[len(f.split("."))-1]=="py"]
        for i in pys:
            Open the file i get the __doc__ string and append it to ret
        for k in folders:
            if(k.__contains__(".")):
                continue
            ret+=self.HtmlFrek(k)
        os.chdir("..")
        del self.loc[len(self.loc)-1]
        return(ret)

    def HtmlProd(self):
        ret = ""
        pys = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.split(".")[len(f.split("."))-1]=="py"]
        for i in pys:
            Open the file i get the __doc__ string and append it to ret
        folders = [f for f in os.listdir(".") if not os.path.isfile(f)]
        for k in folders:
            if(k.__contains__(".")):
                continue
            ret+=self.HtmlFrek(k)
        self.prod = ret
        return(ret)

i = indexer(".")
q=i.HtmlProd()
#print i.prod

w = open("readme.md","w")
w.write(q)
w.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use docmd (I wrote this specifically to address the complexity of answering this kind of question with a reasonable tool).  It's open source, etc.

```
pip install docmd
```

Generate one file:

```
docmd my_module > README.md
```

Generate a whole folder full of documentation:

```
docmd my_module -out docs
```

Does this:

- per-module tree of output
- table-of-contents for root package
- parent-links in submodules
- source links

The documentation for docmd is generated using docmd.

Examples of output:

https://github.com/AtakamaLLC/docmd/blob/master/README.md
https://github.com/AtakamaLLC/omen2/blob/docs/docs/omen2.md